# How difficult is it to get a chinese "L" visa when traveling alone

Tags: visas, china, solo-travel, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino passport holder working in Singapore. I am planning to go to Beijing this August, and I'd just like to know how difficult it is to get a Chinese tourist visa if you are traveling alone (before I buy my ticket).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chinese tourist visas are fairly easy to obtain, although the [Chinese visa agency in Singapore](http://www.visaforchina.com.sg/SGP_EN/visainstruction/249520.shtml) does state that reservations for flights and hotels are required for L visas.  So I would suggest booking refundable flights and a hotel, then applying.  Also, don't apply too early, because the validity of Chinese visas starts the moment they are issued, not on entry to the country.

Comment: Chinese visa requirements are generally quite lax. Thought the website suggests reservations for flight and hotels, in practice these are usually not required.